# How to handle Firestore's timestamp return on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I'd like to treat the **Cloud Firestore** `Timestamp` return on my Angular reactive forms, since the [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) field of the Angular Material only accepts a value of type `Date()`.

In my table also using the Table of the Angular Material I need to insert a pipe in the column where the date is returned to display the date formatted for the user.

```
{{(data.birthDate.seconds * 1000) | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

In my form it does not load the date in the [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) field because it expects a value of type `Date()` and a value of type `Timestamp` is returned.

---

Is there any way to handle this? To return a value of type `Date()` instead of a `Timestamp` value?

I could do this when I return to the collection of my documents, but I can not 
do this because I use a generic class to handle the Cloud Firestore.

This is embarrassing to me because I can not display the date in the [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) field for the user, and when I save the record and go back to my table or form it instead of returning a `Timestamp` value it returns a `Date()` value;

In my model file I tried this, it works but when I save and try to view it again, the following happens:

```
        if (item.birthDate) {
            console.log(item.birthDate);
            const birthDate= birthDate.seconds * 1000;
            this.birthDate = new Date(birthDate);
        }
```

Console log:

```
Timestamp {seconds: 532231200, nanoseconds: 0}

Thu Nov 13 1986 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)
```

Another problem I have also, is that I can not write a date manually in the DatePicker field that it says the date is invalid, I need to trigger the Popup and click on...

It's been a while since I've had this problem and I do not find an exact solution to this problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply map the data when you get the request ?

Comment: Because as I said I use a generic class to return the data, as I use @ ngrx / store in my application and I decided to create a generic class to work with the Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Let me rephrase then : Why don't you simply change your generic class to map the data when you get the request ?

Comment: Because from there can be returned other documents that do not have to do with the type of data that I want to return, they are not all documents where I will have birthDate.

Comment: Then you use an optional property, or you extend a class with this one.